# Removing all language tags from InDesign file

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

When I export my InDesign file that I was given by a designer to HTML there are hundreds of language span tags scattered all over the place. Example below.

How can I remove these language spans from the InDesign file instead of having to remove them manually from the HTML file.

```
<p>
  <span lang="fr-FR"><a id="_idTextAnchor002"></a>En cherchant </span
  ><span lang="ar-SA">à </span
  ><span lang="fr-FR"
    >appuyer un élève, certains pédagogues interviennent personnellement et
    posent des gestes inappropriés<a id="_idTextAnchor003"></a>. D’autres –
    aussi rares soient-ils – ne se préoccupent pas du bienêtre de l’</span
  ><span lang="ar-SA">élève, mais </span><span lang="fr-FR">cherchent</span
  ><span lang="ar-SA"> délibérément</span><span lang="fr-FR"> à le </span
  ><span lang="ar-SA">«</span><span lang="fr-FR">conditionner</span
  ><span lang="ar-SA">»</span
  ><span lang="fr-FR"> dans le but d’entretenir </span
  ><span lang="ar-SA">éventuellement </span
  ><span lang="fr-FR"
    >une relation de nature sexuelle. <a id="_idTextAnchor004"></a>Souvent, ce
    mécanisme, que nous appellerons «pédopiégeage» (</span
  ><span lang="fr-FR">grooming</span
  ><span lang="fr-FR"
    >, en anglais), ne peut être mis au jour qu’après coup, par la police,
    l’employeur, l’Ordre et les victimes elles-m</span
  >ê<span lang="fr-FR">mes. </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

the following one-line AppleScript will remove all language attributes from text in an InDesign layout.

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020" to set applied language of text style ranges of stories of document 1 to (item 1 of languages of document 1 whose name is "[No Language]")
```